# Could not install packages due to a EnvironmentError Pip

Tags: python, pip

I am installing Flask using the `pip install flask` command.

Can somebody help me?

When installing a package I get these errors and warnings:

````
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate is not yet valid (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /packages/7f/17/16267e782a30ea2ce08a9a452c1db285afb0ff226cfe3753f484d3d65662/Django-3.1.3-py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate is not yet valid (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /packages/7f/17/16267e782a30ea2ce08a9a452c1db285afb0ff226cfe3753f484d3d65662/Django-3.1.3-py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate is not yet valid (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /packages/7f/17/16267e782a30ea2ce08a9a452c1db285afb0ff226cfe3753f484d3d65662/Django-3.1.3-py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate is not yet valid (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /packages/7f/17/16267e782a30ea2ce08a9a452c1db285afb0ff226cfe3753f484d3d65662/Django-3.1.3-py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/7f/17/16267e782a30ea2ce08a9a452c1db285afb0ff226cfe3753f484d3d65662/Django-3.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate is not yet valid (_ssl.c:1123)'))) ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have a slow connection to the server. Try increasing the timeout:

```
export PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=120
```

and then do the pip install. You can also try:

```
sudo pip install --default-timeout=120 flask
```

Or if you're trying to install on a corporate network with a firewall in place, can you connect to another WiFi or hot spot and try downloading again?

Comment: Thanks for the help.